# SQL Server: Upgrade CPU or add a second CPU?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Currently have a 2 socket server with a single xeon e5-2407 @2.2Ghz running SQL Server 2012. There are no performance issues at the moment but wondering for the future if it would be better to upgrade the existing CPU (higher clock speed, more cache, etc) or to add an additional matching CPU into the second slot.

Appreciate your advise on pros and cons of each and things I should be aware of.

Thank you!

Comment: If licensing cost isn't an issue, then we can't judge cores by their price either (as licensing cost per core > your cpu cost). In which case it's kind of a weird discussion... If price isn't an issue simply replace the cpu with the most expensive cpu you can buy x2 and populate both sockets...

Answer (score 1):

Within your question: Licensing says upgrade CPU because most likely you are licensed per socket or core. So adding a second processor will cost.

Comment: You're actually going to be hard pressed finding a cpu to replace the E5 series quad cores that is [better with 4 cores](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/78583/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-v3-Family?q=xeon#@All). At the least you'll be looking at 6 cores. Licensing wise you're incurring a pretty significant hit either way. I'd definately opt for a second quad core over replacing it with a six-core processor.

Comment: Thank you both but I'd like to keep licensing considerations out of this and focus primarily on performance.

Comment: @Fahd You can't really keep licensing out of it. Your core licensing [affects your memory usage](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/core-based-licensing-matters-performance-tuning/) as well as your core usage. And should be your primary concern whenever looking at upgrading your CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of RAM is more preferrable as far as you can cache DB indexes into the memory.